# Spring Boot (1.4.1) and Thymeleaf (3) MessageSource single quotes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, internationalization, thymeleaf

I have a question about MessageSource messages in Spring Boot (1.4.1) and Thymeleaf (3).

File app.properties

```
app.quotes=Francesco's title
app.quotes2=Francesco''s title
```

In page.html when I print the messages

```
<h2 th:text="#{app.quotes}"></h2>
<h2 th:utext="#{app.quotes}"></h2>
<h2 th:text="#{app.quotes2}"></h2>
<h2 th:utext="#{app.quotes2}"></h2>
```

I get exactly (th:text or th:utext does not make any difference)

- Francesco's title
- Francesco's title
- Francesco''s title
- Francesco''s title

In my controller

```
private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());    

@Autowired
private MessageSource messages;

@RequestMapping(value="/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String page() {

    String text = messages.getMessage("app.quotes", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    String text2 = messages.getMessage("app.quotes2", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());

    log.debug("text = " + text);
    log.debug("text2 = " + text2);

    // Output
    return "page";
}
```

The text I get logged is

- `text = Francescos title`
- `text2 = Francesco's title`

This is predictable because single quotes in properties messages must be escaped with double single quotes ("Francesco''s title" is supposed to be the correct text).
How can I make Thymeleaf to print the message escaping the double single quotes as MessageSource does, or MessageSource to return the plain text as Thymeleaf does?
I would like not to use different keys/values based on the caller.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will not parse the message as long as it not contains an argument (`app.quote=John's message`) but will do so if it has a one (`app.quote={0}'s message`)

You can override this behavior with `setAlwaysUseMessageFormat`:

```
@Bean
MessageSource defaultMessageSource(){
 org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource source = new org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
source.setAlwaysUseMessageFormat(true);
return source;
}
```

Also take look at [resolveCodeWithoutArguments](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#resolveCodeWithoutArguments-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have set the property **spring.messages.always-use-message-format=true** and now thymeleaf prints correctly all texts with double single quotes.